# npm not able to download the complete grunt plugin and other plugin from cmd in window 8

Tags: gruntjs, npm

After entering the command "npm install grunt --save-dev" in cmd its starts downloading the plugin but the installation never completes ,the loader keeps on running. In the project folder > node_modules folder > grunt folder gets created with lots of missing files. and the loader is still runing i waited for half hour nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem. Problem is related to network setting. In my case i have svn which is using the static network setting to work. To resolve this go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections go to Ethernet Properties change the IPV4 setting to "obtain an IP address automatically" and "obtain DNS server address automatically " -> ok -> restart you pc (if required). Then try npm for installing plugins it will work now..